# Misrepresentation of data due to erroneous registration in the database

Tags: teradata

I'm having a column (Channel) which shows me where the customer took his reservation (Web, Cellular etc..).

The data in this column for one of my products (assume product_id=101)  is incorrect; meaning, the product can be bought only using the Cell phone, but in my data base the channel for this product includes also Web etc..

This make me a troubles because I'm classifying my products according to their channel:

```
Case 
     When Channel in (1001,1002) Then 'Web'
     When Channel in (1050,1051) Then 'Cel'
     etc...
```

Now, I'd like to write the above-mentioned product's (101) channel as 'Cel', and I'm not so sure how to do it.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might modify your CASE: `Case When Channel in (1050,1051) OR  product_id=101 Then 'Cel'
     When Channel in (1001,1002) Then 'Web' etc...`

Comment: It seems to work! Thank you very much!!